# Elementwise array mutliplication in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl, fpga, multiplication

How can I multiply two arrays elementwise.
In Matlab, I could do

```
a[1:6 ] = b[2:7] .* b[1:6]
```

I have tried

```
calc_imag(5 to 7) <= i_real(5 to 7) * i_real(6 to 8);
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

There is no surprise that it does not work. Multiplication in VHDL is very different that multiplication in MATLAB. In your example below :

```
calc_imag(5 to 7) <= i_real(5 to 7) * i_real(6 to 8);
```

The above operation will not compile. You are multiplying a vector of width 3 bits (`i_real(5 to 7)`) with a vector of width 3 bits `i_real(6 to 8)` and expecting a result of 3 bits (`calc_imag(5 to 7)`). The result of this operation can only be stored in a vector of with 6 bits (or more). If your result is required to have width of 3 bits, you will have to either truncate or round the result of the multiplication with additional considerations to retain some level of data accuracy. Either of those two options will result in data loss and reduced data accuracy.

I assume you want to do the following type of multiplication : [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))

Since I have no additional information on data widths and types, I will provide this code I made some while ago (maybe 2 years ago). It is completely combinational, but I synthesized it with different blocks at that time and, as far as I remember, the project this code was part of was synthesizable. There were some timing issue that crept up, but those were handled by registering at either end of the block.

Feel free to see the code below and replicate the parts that you need for your purposes.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

--- Steps:
--- 1) Two 32-bit vectors are recieved as some clock cycle. The controller will handles 
--- enableing MUXing data from register, so no need for clk or rdy/vld handshake.
--- 2) Split the 32bit into eight, 4b signed vectors. 
--- 3) Perform the elementwise muiltiplication : [a b c] * [d e f ] = [a*d b*e c*f]
--- 4) Produce result of length 8b per element pair, and send to output.


entity elementwise_mult is
  port(
    i_elements_1 : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    i_elements_2 : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    o_result     : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
  );
end entity elementwise_mult;

architecture Behavioral of elementwise_mult is

  type elements_arr is array (7 downto 0) of signed(3 downto 0);
  signal elements_1 : elements_arr;
  signal elements_2 : elements_arr;

  type result_arr is array (7 downto 0) of signed(7 downto 0);
  signal mult_result_arr : result_arr;

begin

  get_elements_g : for e in 0 to 7 generate
    elements_1(e) <= signed(i_elements_1(e*4+4-1 downto e*4));
    elements_2(e) <= signed(i_elements_2(e*4+4-1 downto e*4));
  end generate get_elements_g;

  perform_elementwise_mult_p : process(elements_1, elements_2)

  begin
    -- since we have two sign bits (one in each element), the actual width of the result
    -- is 7b (1 sign bit, and 6b data), but 8b are used for consistancy with later blocks. 
    multiplication_loop : for mult in 0 to 7 loop
      mult_result_arr(mult) <= elements_1(mult) * elements_2(mult);
    end loop multiplication_loop;

  end process perform_elementwise_mult_p;

  get_results_g : for result in 0 to 7 generate
    o_result(result*8+8-1 downto result*8) <= std_logic_vector(mult_result_arr(result));
  end generate get_results_g;

end architecture Behavioral;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You must use a loop and multiply the elements one after the other. But you could hide this in a function or even overload the multiplication operator with the function.